# Turn off PostBack on a menu click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, pagination

I have pagination in an UpdatePanel.

I have a dropdownlist that controls which field will be sorted on.

I have added both the sort button and the pagination menu as AsyncPostBackTriggers.  My sort button works fine, but my pagination menu resets the sort dropdownlist to the default value every time I click it.  When I step through the code, I can see the sort button fires the (!IsPostBack) section, and the pagination menu fires the "Else" section of my page load.

So, I can click any page and it works fine.  I can sort and it will return the proper records sorted *for that page*.  When I click on a page number again, the sort returns to the default.  I want to allow my users to sort one time and then page through the sorted data.

So, how can I turn off PostBack on a menu?

My relevant code looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="150">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboSortBy" runat="server" Width="120" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                <asp:ListItem Value="StatusText">Benefit Type</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="PRIORITY_RANK">Priority Rank</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ACTIVE_FLG">Active Flag</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td width="180"><asp:Button ID="btnSort" runat="server" 
            Text="Sort" Width="121px" onclick="btnSort_Click" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" />
<br />
<div class="clear" id="NavDiv" style="width:1000px; margin:0 auto; display: table;">
    <asp:Menu ID="NavMenu" runat="server" CssClass="navmenu" 
        IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" width="703px"
        BackColor="#CC3300">
        <Items> 
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="First" Selectable="true" />
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<table width="570">
<tr>
<td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="NavMenu" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSort" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="BenTypeRepeater" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr bgcolor="#007ACC" style="color:White">
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2"></td>
            <tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>  
            <tr>  
                <td colspan="5"></td>  
            </tr>  
        </SeparatorTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **AutoPostBack="true"** to dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboSortBy" runat="server" Width="120" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="StatusText">Benefit Type</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="PRIORITY_RANK">Priority Rank</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ACTIVE_FLG">Active Flag</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: That didn't do it.  :o(